# Google App Engine, How to make native file object?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to convert some data got from urlfetch to native python file object.
Does anyone know how to do this?

I understand GAE can't save files to local.
But I need file object due to library's specification.

Answer (score 4):

You can use python's [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html) class to wrap a a file-like object around any data retrieved by URL Fetch.

If you use python's [urllib2.urlopen()](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) instead of Google's URL Fetch API, you'll get a file-like object which might work with your library.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a file-like object, you can use [urllib2](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview.html#Fetching_URLs_in_Python), which on GAE is a wrapper around urlfetch.  `urlopen` returns the file-like object.  I don't know of a way you could get a true file handle for a downloaded URL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I got `AttributeError: addinfourl instance has no attribute 'name'`. It seems this library needs file name.