# Open a file from urlfetch in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I'm trying to open a file in GAE that was retrieved using `urlfetch()`.

Here's what I have so far:

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

result = urlfetch.fetch('http://example.com/test.txt')
data = result.content
## f = open(...) <- what goes in here?
```

This might seem strange but there's a **very similar** function in the BlobStore that can write `data` to a blobfile:

```
f = files.blobstore.create(mime_type='txt', _blobinfo_uploaded_filename='test')
with files.open(f, 'a') as data:
    data.write(result.content)
```

How can I write `data` into an arbitrary file object?

Edit: Should've been more clear; I'm trying to urlfetch **any** file and open `result.content` in a file object. So it might be a .doc instead of a .txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yoy do not have to open a file. You have received the txt data in data = result.content.

Comment: Yes, but I need to store the text data inside a file object. And also, if the file were a .doc then the data in result.content would not be just plain text.

Comment: What file object? You can add the content (the file data = a blob) to the blobstore and give it the corresponding mimetype. In this way I download images or a pdf and save them in the blobstore. Your fetch receives a blob of data.

Comment: I mean a file object that's created from `f = open('text.txt')`. Sounds stupid, but I do need it like this since I'm not putting the data in the BlobStore. (In case you're curious, I'm passing in `f` as a parameter for a gdata.MediaSource object)

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. But for reading the data (blob) you do not have to open a file because you have received the data. For saving it you have to create a file first. Look for that in the Google Drive API. Conclusion: Your question is: how to save fetched data in Google Drive.

Comment: Yes it is! Haha, I narrowed it down to this specific problem step though. I actually just edited the gdata library I was using to work without the file object requirement, so now it's working with just `result.content`. However, I just found a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360064/google-app-engine-how-to-make-native-file-object) about this that might help some future users. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the StringIO module to emulate a file object using the contents of your string.

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
from StringIO import StringIO

result = urlfetch.fetch('http://example.com/test.txt')
f = StringIO(result.content)
```

You can then read() from the f object or use other file object methods like seek(), readline(), etc.