# Getting a file with urlfetch and saving it to the Google datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore, blobstore, urlfetch

I have read [Open a file from urlfetch in GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12682983/2314737) and [Google App Engine, How to make native file object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5360064/2314737) but still can't figure out how to save a .pdf file from an URL to the Google datastore or blobstore.
Any hint or a pointer to a working example?

I'm using Python and my code is essentially the one from https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/?hl=it-IT&csw=1

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

url = "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/1342/1342-pdf.pdf"
result = urlfetch.fetch(url)
if result.status_code == 200:
  doSomethingWithResult(result.content)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like

First your model to store the PDF in

```
class PDFStore(ndb.Model):
  content = ndb.BlobProperty()
```

The create an instance of that model, put the data into it the save it.

```
def doSomethingWithResult(result):
    PDF = result.content

    blobstore_data = PDFStore()

    blobstore_data.content = PDF

    blobstore_data.put()
```

It's exactly as in the first link you put up: [Open a file from urlfetch in GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682983/open-a-file-from-urlfetch-in-gae)

Comment: Confused variable names. Since a BlobStore is a collection of blobs, a `PDFStore` would be a collection of PDFs. `blobstore_data` would be simply `blob`. Then you'd have `blob = result.content; pdf = PDF(); pdf.content = blob`.